# Linking Subnets Over DDWRT Wireless Client

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt, subnet

This ones had me going for a few days. I have a Uverse supplied Motorola NVG589 that supplies our TV, phone, and wireless internet. In my room I have some networking gear which include an ASUS RT-AC68U flashed with DDWRT. These two devices are different networks. The ATT RG is 192.168.1.0/24 and the ASUS router in my room is 192.168.0.0/24.

Now what Im trying to do is have my synology box in my room with address 192.168.0.101 (The ASUS router) become availible to stream media to our chromecast which connects to our ATT wireless gateway. It has to be connected to the ATT modem because wireless coverage is better through the entire house.

I was thinking I could use an extra port on my synology box and use some kind of low layer briging technique to assign it an address from my ATT modem thus becoming visible to the 192.168.1.0 network and chromecast.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I am a visual person so I put your question in a picture:

[image: Current situation]

As I read it your green network (on the Asus router&wireless access point with DDWRT) is not connected at all to the orange network.

If I am wrong then no extra cable is needed. You just need to tell the Motorola NVG589 that it needs to route packets for the 192.168.0.0/24 network to the Asus router. This is assuming that a ISP provided modem offers this functionality. YOu might be able to do this wirelessly by adding two IPs to the Asus router. One IP on its onw 'green' network (and the default gateway for devices on the green network) and one IP in the 192.168.1.0/24 network to communicate with the orange network.

Nice, clean, no extra cables. But wireless and likely not best performance.

For better performance you could do the same with a wired cable between the Motorola and the Asus router.

Thirdly you mention: `I could use an extra port on my synology box`. From this I deduce that the Synology NAS is multihomed. In which case you could indeed run two cables from it. One to the green router, one to the orange one. The NAS would be reachable by both IPs. No low layer bridging is needed, just give each NIC on the NAS its own IP.